# Solaris 9 - Word Count (wc) command gives wrong output

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, solaris

When i use **'ps', 'egrep'** and **'wc'** command to count number of processes, it gives me wrong value. I am running the command in **'Solaris 9'** machine. Please assist in understanding the issue.

```
MyServer $ ps -fu root | egrep -v 'bash|ksh|ssh|ef|mailx|nohup|defunct|ps|sh|FND'
     UID   PID  PPID  C    STIME TTY      TIME CMD
 root 16267 16171  0   Jan 28 ?        0:18 xyz
 root 16269 16171  0   Jan 28 ?        0:07 abc
 root 16268 16171  0   Jan 28 ?        0:07 ghi
MyServer $
```

Only 4 (3 processes + header) lines shown in output. But when i use below command it returns the output as **5**

```
MyServer $ ps -fu root | egrep -v 'bash|ksh|ssh|ef|mailx|nohup|defunct|ps|sh|FND' | wc -l
       5
```

On the otherhand, when I echo the output to a file and count the number of lines, it works perfectly normal.

```
MyServer $ ps -fu root | egrep -v 'bash|ksh|ssh|ef|mailx|nohup|defunct|ps|sh|FND' >temp && cat temp | wc -l
       4
```

Comment: Can you pipe the first example to `hexdump -Cv` and give the results?

Comment: What is the output of `alias egrep` ?

Comment: @iBug 
Unfortunately _**hexdump**_ is not availble in my server.

`bash: hexdump: command not found`

Comment: @janos 

`MyServer $ alias egrep
bash: alias: `egrep' not found`

Comment: If available, install the package `bsdmainutils` from your package provider. The `hexdump` should be available. Or you can use `busybox` instead.

Comment: The 'wc' command was showing up on another line in the output, that wasn't showing up in the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's counting the `wc` process, which won't show up when the output for `ps` is being piped to a file.

Try this:

```
ps -fu root | egrep -v 'wc|bash|ksh|ssh|ef|mailx|nohup|defunct|ps|sh|FND' | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks. That should be the issue. 